# Purpose of python antigravity module

Tags: python, import, python-antigravity

I was just digging up some cool modules in python, and this `antigravity` module seems cool, and full of potentials, but I am not sure if it is what it sounds like.

Is there any use for it other than displaying the comic page on a browser? If there is, please do tell what it can be used for. Is there an example? Note that below in the link, that when the guy asks "But how are you flying?", the python dude answers, "I just typed import antigravity."

I was wondering if there actually is a way to make things fly by just importing antigravity, maybe in Pygame or other cross-platforms modules.

Here is the [link](https://xkcd.com/353/)...

```
import antigravity
def main():
    antigravity.fly()
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You could look at the source code, which will show you there's not much going on: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/antigravity.py

Comment: https://www.xkcd.com/353/ kind of peculiar computer science humor.

Comment: The comic came before it, and the module is a reference to it.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

No, it's just an [easter egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)). [This brief blog post](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/import-antigravity.html) has a bit more detail.

Answer (score 54):

It's an [easter egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)). Here are some more, have fun!

```py
>>> import __hello__
Hello world!
```

```py
>>> import __phello__
Hello world!
```

```py
>>> from __future__ import braces
SyntaxError: not a chance
```

```py
>>> hash(float('inf'))
314159
```

```py
>>> hash(-1)
-2
```

```py
>>> from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL
>>> 1 <> 2
True
>>> 1 != 2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1 != 2
      ^^
SyntaxError: with Barry as BDFL, use '<>' instead of '!='
```

```py
>>> import types
>>> help(types.CodeType)
Help on class code in module builtins:

class code(object)
 |  ...
 |
 |  Create a code object.  Not for the faint of heart.
 |
...
```

```py
>>> import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```